# move cursor position by one word

Tags: javascript

I'm making a "text-checker" which uses contenteditable element and Mark.js.

Once the user inputs some text, some of it may be marked. When that happens (text is marked) the cursor jumps to the beginning of that word. I haven't found a way to fix the problem.

What I would like to do, is see if the cursor (caret) is located adjacent to the `<mark>` element, and if so move the cursor to the end of the word.

*Edit:* Sharking an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/p5mxa2s8/)

Lets say the cursor is represented by |.

```
<div class="textarea" contenteditable="true" id="textarea">
   Some text and |<mark class="c-o">some</mark> more text.
</div>
```

What I would like in this case is a function to move the cursor here.

```
<div class="textarea" contenteditable="true" id="textarea">
   Some text and <mark class="c-o">some</mark>| more text.
</div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: could you please share what you tried and sample snippet.

Comment: Can you add your relevant JS code?

Comment: Sorry about that. Edit the questioned, added fiddle